# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager while using resteasy for a rest client call from an EJB

Tags: rest, ejb, wildfly, resteasy

I'm facing an issue on `Wildfly 13` when using rest easy to call services as a client.

I deploy many EJB projects inside an `ear`. Dependencies are managed by maven except libraries provides by the `wildfly 13` application Server (from module folder). I make deployment with the latest version of JBoss Tools.

My app publishes some rest services as a server. When I call those web services (from postman for eg), every thing is fine. The rest API `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs 3.5.1` provided by Wildfly works without issue as expected.

But my app needs also to connect to an external rest web service, this time as a client. I've coded a stateless EJB instantiating a WebTarget targeting the provided URL (that is the target of the external rest service) :

```
protected void setTarget(URL target) throws FmRestApiException {
    try {
        String sUrl = target.toString();
        this.target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(sUrl);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new FmRestApiException("Can't initialize FM Rest API to target "+target,e);
    }
}
```

But when I launched the call, Wildfly can't build the webtarget and resteasy throws the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ClientHttpEngineBuilder4.build(ClientHttpEngineBuilder4.java:110)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.buildOld(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:381)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:390)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:38)
    at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
    at com.novarem.commons.fmapi.rest.AbstractFmApiRestClient.setTarget(AbstractFmApiRestClient.java:37)
    at fr.remmedia.fmadapter.FmRestApiGateway.init(FmRestApiGateway.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doLifecycleInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:122)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceFieldInjectionInterceptorFactory.java:112)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:28)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInterceptorInjectionInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsCreateInterceptor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
    ... 270 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager from [Module "org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" version 3.5.1.Final from local module loader @4c40b76e (finder: local module finder @2ea6137 (roots: /Library/JBoss/wildfly-remmedia-13/modules,/Library/JBoss/wildfly-remmedia-13/modules/system/layers/base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
```

I'm aware about incompatibility of versions between resteasy and apache httpcomponents packages provided as modules in former versions of Wildfly. But in Wildfly 13, the `org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs` is up to version 3.5.1 and `org.apache.httpcomponents` is up to version 4.5.2 for httpclient, 4.4.4 for httpcore, 4.1.3 for for httpasyncclient and 4.5.2 for httpmime.

Does anybody faced the same issue ? Else, does anybody has got an idea about how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue. Actually, module org.apache.httpcomponents is not loaded by default by Wildfly meanwhile the resteasy module has got a dependency with it. So just force the loading of the module into the standalone.xml/domain.xml deployment file as written below :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="org.apache.httpcomponents"/>
    </global-modules>
    ...
</subsystem>
```